# Unable to ignore formula column in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

Newer to google sheets/java scripts.. In the function below its grabbing the data from the source sheet correctly and entering it in the next available cell on the destination correctly. However, I have a formula in column F cells for the whole sheet. As the getLastRow does its work the data gets pasted way down the sheet. What do I need to change to what in the function below to ignore column F in the checks?

```
function CopyTime() {
  var sourceSheet = "Data";
  var sourceCell = "E61";
  var destinationSheet = "Log";
  var destinationCell = "E6";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourceValue = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheet).getRange(sourceCell).getValue();
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName(destinationSheet);
  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(destinationCell);
  var destRow = destRange.getRow();
  var destCol = destRange.getColumn();
  var destValues = destSheet.getRange(destRow, destCol, Math.max(1, destSheet.getLastRow() - destRow + 1)).getValues();
  for (var i = destValues.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (destValues[i]) break;
  }
  if (destValues[i] != "") i = i + 1;
  destSheet.getRange(destRow + i, destCol).setValue(sourceValue);
}
```

Comment: I don't see where the function interacts with column F.

Comment: Yeah that is the problem, I'm not telling it to. Column F just has a formula that takes the data from the adjacent cell in column E and spits out a value. But if the formula is there then the E values writes to the next line.

Comment: I can't help you unless you can explain it better or provide an example of what's happening.

Comment: Ok Ill try... The function above gets a value from a data sheet and then copies the content to a log sheet, where it is expected to paste into column E at the next available row. Lets say the next available row is 6, as there is no data currently in E6. If there is a formula in F6 at the time of running the function above the data will not go into E6, it will instead enter E7 or whatever the next row is that does Not have the formula in F. In my sheet I have the formula entered into Column F, cells 1-20. If I run the column E function above, the data is entered into E21. Does that help?

Comment: Why does it not go to E6 because of the formula?  What is the formula?

Comment: Yes, if I remove the formula from F6 then E6 is populated.

=IF (ISBLANK (LOG!E6), "", if((-(now()-LOG!E6))>0,(- (now()-LOG!E6)),"COMPLETE"))

Comment: I think you need to share your sheet at this stage, or give a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can try to reproduce this. Though, maybe its due to what is in `E61`?

Comment: ok, hopefully i did this right. Here is the link to the sheet, there are some hidden reference sheets. let me know if this works when you make a copy or if there is more I need to do. 

<https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EV_Yp-Gd8QWd2hlqD2u4WrhNClNZxJ8cTGpdA6ZOz0c/edit?usp=sharing>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The issue is with the conditional statement

If I understood correctly, you are trying to identify the last row with a value in column E, so that you can input a value after it.

```js
for (var i = destValues.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (destValues[i]) break;
}
```

Specifically, the problem lies with the condition `if (destValues[i])`

#### Explanation

As you know, when you grab values from a sheet, you get a 2D array. In this function, you are just getting column E but that still returns a 2D array:

```js
[
    [ 'Content' ],
    [ '' ],
    [ '' ],
    [ '' ],
    [ '' ],
    [ '' ],
    [ '' ],
    [ '' ],
    [ '' ],
]
```

Your method is to loop through this array backwards to get the index number of the cell with content.

When you wrote your condition, I believe you assumed the following:

1. If `[ '' ] == false` is `true`
2. Then `if ([ '' ]) break` will evaluate to `false` which will not `break`.

This seems reasonable, however, if you use the `Boolean` function to simlulate `if ([ '' ])` in isolation:

```
Boolean([ '' ]) // this produces true!
```

So your script would test the last row and `break` and this is why its getting placed into the last row. (I really don't see how the formula is related to this at all).

This equality was admittedly unexpected when coming at it from this context. Though it makes sense if you consider that often you want to test whether an array is empty. `['']` being an array with one element, and so there is some logic in considering it as `true`, and yet it could also be considered logical to consider it `false`.

Unfortunately this is the reason that JavaScript has a lot of these unexpected Boolean conversion issues, so my advice would be, when developing in JavaScript, double check your assumptions about what equals what!

<sup>(Try Google "Javascript equality memes")</sup>

#### Solution

```js
// ...

console.log("searching for non empty cell")
for (var i=destValues.length-1;i>=0;--i) {
  if (destValues[i][0] != "") {
    console.log("found non empty row!")
    break
  };
}

// ...
```

#### Reference

- [Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean)

Comment: Awesome, I was able to try it out and it worked as expected. Thanks for clearing this up for me. I will have to keep this in mind when using Boolean in JS.